# Document using YARD an instance method's return type that returns instance of class

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I couldn't find this anywhere including Yard's documentation.

I am looking to document an instance method's return type. For example,

```
class Foo
  def initialize
  end
end
```

I am documenting it as

```
@return [???] returns the instance of `Foo`
```

What should I write in ??? Should it be `Foo`?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, as per [tags overview](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Type_List_Conventions) it mentions the following:

> **Class or Module Types**
>
> Any Ruby type is allowed as a class or module type. Such a type is simply the  name of the class or module.

Comment: if `@return [Foo]` indicates that an instance is returned, how would one show that a method returns `Foo` as a class?

Comment: With `@return [Class<Foo>]`, according to https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1109